# How do I open two files side-by-side in Sublime Text 3 Editor?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I want to open two files (`html`, `js`) files for better productivity, and I can't use any third party packages at my office.

Is there any way to open two files in side-by-side in Sublime Text 3?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To open two files side by side in Sublime Text 3 do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and then do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>. To move back to one windowed mode just do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and then do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>.

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20191016184133/http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_management/file_navigation.html#panes) is the Documentation for that feature.

Comment: The link to the documentation appears to be broken/outdated.

Answer (score 6):

view > layout > Column 2

[image: visual presentation]

Comment: With VS Code one can easily compare files using file context menu `Select for Compare` and `Compare with Selected`